# How to fix pdf.js find/highlight error or what causes it

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js and viewer.js to show pdf documents on our web site and find/highlight words. Everything is ok except that when I 'find/highlight all' a word, the highlights are misplaced and they are placed above/under the right words. I attach an image:

http://movelex.hu/fenyoapa/pdfjs_highlight_error.jpg

it is showing my problem well. The red circles are the right words to highlight.

After a lot of debugging finally I tried it with the native ctrl+f and I realized that not my program makes mistake but it is buggy natively.

Meanwhile I got familiar with viewer.js and its functions, but I can't resolve this problem.

And in some cases (some PDF docs) it is working well, in some not.

Here is a live example (open in FireFox):

http://movelex.hu/fenyoapa/tori_6_tk_webre.pdf_150.pdf

press ctrl+f and type 'az'.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to report your issue as a bug at the PDF.js bug tracker: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5355. Since the bug is only triggered after a search, I would put a breakpoint in the method that is responsible for searching (which could be found by putting a breakpoint on the click event handler of the search button).

Comment: I've merged your solution to our project and it works great. Many thanks. I want to mark this as the solution to the question but I don't know how.

Comment: I could write an answer about the steps that I followed to isolate and fix the problem if you're interested.

Comment: Oops I've found some other error, but maybe it is the thing that you mention on Github (text outside the page's view). Would you take a look at it: http://movelex.hu/fenyoapa/pdfjs_highlight_error2.jpg
the up-down direction looks ok but now it is shifted to the right.

Comment: Possibly a different issue. I don't have the time to look into it right now. I've reported it as https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5358. How did you generate this PDF file?